# Typing Error using Ramda Pipe in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

I am using Ramda's `pipe` method. It runs fine but it is giving some **type error** on first argument `flatten`.

I am not sure what it is about. Can anyone please explain the issue?

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ramda-playground-vcljpy

Error:

[image]

Sorry for naive title

Thanks

Comment: If it helps, because this works in the [REPL](http://fourwindssoft.com/link/7), this is probably something that should be asked of whoever maintains your TS typings file.

Comment: I am maintaining TS typings file but I am not sure what I am missing there. It is some typing issue or the way I am calling mergeData.  I am not sure! :/

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Ramda typings file.  Ramda does not natively support TS, and I know there are several groups out there who maintain TS typings for Ramda.  But I never remember details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly supply the types to `R.pipe`:

```
const mergeData: any = pipe<
  [Data[][]], // arguments supplied to the pipe
  Data[], // result of flatten
  Data[], // result of filter
  Record<string, Data[]>, // result of groupBy
  Data[][], // result of values
  Data[], // result of map(combine)
  RankedData[] // result of last
>(
```

This works with the following packages' versions and above:

```
"@types/ramda": "0.27.34",
"ramda": "0.27.1"
```

This is the code of the working example ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ramda-pipe-with-typescript-zrrmp?file=/src/index.ts)):

```
interface Data {
  name: string;
  val: number;
}

interface RankedData extends Data {
  rank: string;
}

const ranks = {
  a: 'si',
  b: 'dp',
  d: 'en',
  c: 'fr'
};

// merge deep and combine val property values
const combine = mergeWithKey((k, l, r) => (k === 'val' ? l + r : r));

const mergeData: any = pipe<
  [Data[][]],
  Data[],
  Data[],
  Record<string, Data[]>,
  Data[][],
  Data[],
  RankedData[]
>(
  flatten,
  filter((o: Data) => Object.keys(ranks).includes(o.name)),
  groupBy(prop('name')), // group by the name
  values, // convert back to an array of arrays
  map(reduce(combine, {} as Data)), // combine each group to a single object
  map((o) => ({
    ...o,
    rank: ranks[o.name]
  }))
);
```

Answer (score 6):

I usually explicitly type the first function in the pipe by making it pointed `(x: Data[][]) => flatten(x)` The rest of the typings should follow nicely